# Openstreetmap - How to edit and delete things from the map

Tags: openstreetmap

I fixed a lot of things in my local area like deleted places that don't exist anymore, moved things to the correct location and added new things to the map.

When I open up maps.me, the only edits that are visible are new hotels and restaurants and things I added to the map. But anything I deleted or moved doesnt show on the map. Also some places I added to the map dont show so its selectively choosing which new places I add.

I dont understand it, how can I make ALL my edits go live?

Answer (score 0):

All your edits are immediately live. It just takes some time for OSM-based software to pick up your changes. Each software has a different update delay. I don't know the details for Maps.ME. If you want to see your changes almost immediately (after 1-2 hours) checkout OsmAnd with the live subscription. This allows you to get hourly map updates.